# Authorize from NextJs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I have an error from NextAuth on authorize(credentials). I have already tried googling the error, asked chatgpt and looked on many websites. I have not found anything so I am trying my luck here. Please help me I am not getting anywhere

```
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import NextAuth, { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@next-auth/prisma-adapter";
import prisma from "@/app/libs/prismadb";

export const authOptions: AuthOptions = {
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "email", type: "text" },
        password: { label: "password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials?.password) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        });

        if (!user || !user?.password) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }

        const isCorrectPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
          credentials.password,
          user.password
        );

        if (!isCorrectPassword) {
          throw new Error("Invalid credentials");
        }

        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

Error: https://paste.md-5.net/wibutefado.coffeescript

Comment: Looks like user IDs are stored as numbers in your database, but NextAuth expects them to be strings. So, I suggest returning instead of `user`, `{ ...user, id: String(user.id) }` if applicable.